# How can I get a British relative's birth certificate for a visa application?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, documentation

In the event you're applying for an Ancestry visa and require your grandparent's birth certificate, how can one get an official copy of said certificate that would be acceptable in an application?

Answer (score 8):

I had to do this for my Ancestry Visa application.  My relative's certificate was not easily accessible to me, so I found out that it's possible to [order a copy of a birth, death or a marriage certificate online](https://www.gov.uk/order-copy-birth-death-marriage-certificate).

You’ll need to register on the [General Register Office (GRO) website](https://www.gro.gov.uk/gro/content/certificates/default.asp) to order a copy of a birth, adoption, death, marriage or civil partnership certificate in England and Wales. Certificates cost £9.25. You can use this service to help you research your family tree.

There's a different process for Scottish and Northern Ireland certificates, linked to on that site.

Comment: For best results when applying, you will need a "GRO Index Reference Number" to identify the specific individual you need the document for.

The [FreeBMD search page](http://www.freebmd.org.uk/cgi/search.pl) allows you to search a crowdsourced copy of the indexes. Alternatively, sites like [Ancestry.Com](http://ancestry.com/) provide free trials and advanced search options.